# Angular can't render list for passed HTML

Tags: angular

Angular is removing button

[image]

This is my render function which later on is getting pass
[image]

this is how I'm passing to lower order component
    [image]

This is how lower order component looks like

[image]

Any Ideas how to do it?

Comment: Please paste the actual code and **not** images of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that a button is a potential security issue. 
If you take a look in your console, angular should print something like:

> WARNING: sanitizing HTML stripped some content, see
>   http://g.co/ng/security#xss

To provide "clean" HTML you have to sanitize it first.
Luckily, Angular has a class called [DomSanitizer](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer) onboard.

TS:

```
constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

public getHtml() {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(`<span><button>Click</button></span>`);
}
```

HTML:

```
<div [innerHtml]="getHtml()"></div>
```

This should work for you.

Also a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2zhxjr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) here